# MCAR (Multivariate Conditional Autoregressive) model in R

Tags: r, regression, spatial

I am performing a spatial analysis of student grades according to their city of origin using R. I have several covariates such as poverty, education and socio-cultural indices. So far I have fitted univariate models such as: linear regression, weighted linear regression and CAR (conditional autoregressive).

Now, I am reading "*Hierarchical Modeling and Analysis for Spatial Data*" from Banerjee, Carlin and Gelfand. I am interested in applying multivariate models, in particular a **MCAR** (Multivariate Conditional Autoregressive) model.

However, I have not found any code in R (or Python) that has it implemented. The most possible has been the "**spatialreg**" library that includes univariate CAR and SAR models.

Is there any library that you know of that includes them? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found "CARBayes" package. This works perfectly for fitting MCAR model.